# Finding solution in TopCoder Arena

Tags: java

I try solve some problem in the arena, but now I can not find it there. I just have a text of solution:

### DEFINITION

Class Name: `MatchMaker`
Method Name: `getBestMatches`
Paramaters: `String[], String, int`
Returns: `String[]`

Method signature (be sure your method is public):

```
String[] getBestMatches(String[] members, String currentUser, int sf);
```

### PROBLEM STATEMENT

A new online match making company needs some software to help find the “perfect
couples”. People who sign up answer a series of multiple-choice questions.
Then, when a member makes a “Get Best Mates” request, the software returns a
list of users whose gender matches the requested gender and whose answers to
the questions were equal to or greater than a similarity factor when compared
to the user’s answers.

Implement a class `MatchMaker`, which contains a method `getBestMatches`. The
method takes as parameters a `String[] members`, `String currentUser`, and an 
`int sf`. Here `members` contains information about all the members. Elements of `members` are of the form

```
 NAME G D X X X X X X X X X X
```

- `NAME` represents the member’s name
- `G` represents the gender of the current user.
- `D` represents the requested gender of the potential mate.
- Each `X` indicates the member’s answer to one of the multiple-choice
  questions. The first `X` is the answer to the first question, the second is the
  answer to the second question, et cetera.
- `currentUser` is the name of the user who made the “Get Best Mates” request.
- `sf` is an integer representing the similarity factor.

Can you help me, and tell how to find a solution in the TopCoder arena?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about how to use the Top Coder website and as such not on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the problem archive to find out which SRM or tournament the class was used in. 
http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive

this will show you the top submissions from each of the acceptable programming languages. You can also use the summary button if you know which SRM the class is from but this does not guarantee that the solution you view is correct if the problem was an old one.